# REST validation handling in Vert.x

Tags: java, vert.x

I'm following the [example](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web-api-contract/java/#_http_requests_validation) from the official documentation but I haven't been able to figure out how error handling works.

If I do `routingContext.fail(400)` from the route handler it goes into an infinite loop. If I don't the router handler is not called.

**Route handler**

```java
HTTPRequestValidationHandler validationHandler = HTTPRequestValidationHandler.create().addPathParam("id", ParameterType.UUID);
router.get("/api/job/:id")
    .handler(validationHandler)
    .handler(jobController::getJob)
    .failureHandler((routingContext) -> {
        Throwable failure = routingContext.failure();
        if (failure instanceof ValidationException) {
            // Something went wrong during validation!
            String validationErrorMessage = failure.getMessage();
            //routingContext.fail(400);
          }
        });
```

**Router handler**

```java
router.errorHandler(400, routingContext -> {
      if (routingContext.failure() instanceof ValidationException) {
        final JsonObject error = new JsonObject()
          .put("timestamp", System.nanoTime())
          .put("error", routingContext.failure().getMessage())
          .put("exception", routingContext.failure().getStackTrace().toString());
        routingContext.response().setStatusCode(400).end(error.encode());

      } else {
        // Unknown 400 failure happened
        routingContext.response().setStatusCode(400).end();
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

`routingContext.fail()` fails again the context, so it causes an infinite loop executing always the specific failure handler of `/api/job/:id`. If you want to execute the next failure handler (in this case, the 400 error handler of router), you must call `routingContext.next()`

If you need a particular error handling for endpoint `/api/job/:id`, use the specific failure handler and *write the response*.
If you don't need any particular error handling and you just want to use a general one for error 400, use `router.errorHandler()` without adding any particular failure handler to the endpoint

Answer (score 0):

According to the `router.errorHandler()` implementation

> The handler will be called when the context fails and other failure handlers didn't write the reply or when an exception is thrown inside an handler.
>   So if we wish to catch the error in the specific route error handling but still delecate it to the router error handler we need to throw a runtime exception from the route handler.

**Route handler**

```java
HTTPRequestValidationHandler validationHandler = HTTPRequestValidationHandler.create().addPathParam("id", ParameterType.UUID);
router.get("/api/job/:id")
    .handler(validationHandler)
    .handler(jobController::getJob)
    .failureHandler((routingContext) -> {
        Throwable failure = routingContext.failure();
        if (failure instanceof ValidationException) {
            throw new RuntimeException(failure.getMessage());
          }
        });
```

Also modified toe error code to 500 to capture all errors and have the error type logic inside the router error handler.

**Router handler**

```java
router.errorHandler(500, routingContext -> {
      if (routingContext.failure() instanceof ValidationException) {
        final JsonObject error = new JsonObject()
          .put("timestamp", System.nanoTime())
          .put("error", routingContext.failure().getMessage())
          .put("exception", routingContext.failure().getStackTrace().toString());
        routingContext.response().setStatusCode(400).end(error.encode());

      } else {
        // Unknown 400 failure happened
        routingContext.response().setStatusCode(400).end();
      }
    });
```